# Combine two iOS apps into one

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, app-store

I have a situation where two separate companies wish to 'join' their iOS apps together to form a single app (so that only one App store download is required).  The apps have entirely separate code-bases.  The companies are looking to partner together but they don't really want one another seeing each others code.

A degree of fiddling with the code would be acceptable.

Is there any way to 'package' the code-bases or binaries so that app 1 could be incorporated into app2 without the app2 developers having access to the app 1 code base?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, make one (or both) of the apps into libaries or frameworks that can be called into from the other (to instantiate and open a XIB file and view controller which is the parent view of the "other" app).

Then the source code could be kept separate and distinct from one section to another.

But you would also have to work out solutions for what to do with any app delegate (UIApplicationDelegate) methods that are implemented in both applications.  Good luck with that!

Comment: I agree, along those lines you have to negotiate between the two just which app is swallowing which.  That's more than just the app delegate, one app should probably leave the store...

Answer (score 0):

You can also create multiple frameworks of your different modules and then import your frameworks which keeps your code separate and easy to manage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).