# Can I bundle /package two apps into one?

Tags: ios, ios7

I have two apps. The first one checks for passwords and credentials and if all is well, then launches the second app. Can I bundle/package the two apps into one? The intent is to present the whole thing as a single app to the Appstore.

1. Is this approach supported for iOS and accepted by Apple?
2. How about framework? Although I think a customised framework is not supported for iOS which is of no use to my case.

Any hints or code samples as how to achieve this (if at all possible) is very much appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No you can not bundle two app in one, Apple does not allow this in iOS. The framework option will work as long as you compile it into one binary. Not completely sure but I think iOS 8 will lift some of these restrictions.

Comment: Sure you can, [see this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10928789/1091539

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Already consulted the suggested article but did not fully grasp the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't bundle two apps, but you can write your own framework that checks credentials and add that to your app. From the information you give, I can't see the reason why you need to put credential checking into an extra framework. Can't you do the check inside your app?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Basically I wanted to avoid re-writing the whole code (PW, credentials checking). But if I have to, well, I guess I've got no other choice! As for writing my own framework, wouldn't it be considered as a private framework which, according to  Apples' documentations, is not supported for iOS. Or did I misunderstand this bit?

Comment: In my understanding a private framework is a framework made by Apple and accesses functionality other developers are not allowed to access. What you (probably) want to do is your own framework, which is perfectly okay with Apple. see: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/Frameworks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create a library for Login (where you can check the credentials of user once authentication is success use protocols to send the information of user or the status (success or failure) to the main app where your total application is presented).  Creating a library (.a and .h) file is easy here you can't use Xib files and images for this you need to create a new bundle where all your Xib's and images are added for library purpose. In other case you can use images as a base64 string. So your total app is now splitter into 2 parts 1. Library for Login 2.All other features.  If you need more information on this please let me know.

Hope this will give you an idea and helpful